# Can I create a symlink that will ignore subdirectories?

Tags: files, symlink, dropbox

I'm trying to get dropbox symlinked to the relevant folders in `/home`. I'd like to symlink them like this:

`~/Dropbox/Pictures --> ~/Pictures`

`~/Dropbox/Camera Uploads --> ~/Pictures/Camera Uploads`

If I do that it will work but I'll have two copies of my pictures and videos stored on Dropbox. I don't want to waste space.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Why not just move your `~/Dropbox/Camera Uploads` folder to `~/Dropbox/Pictures`? Problem solved, no wasted space, no messing with symlinks inside symlinked directories.

Comment: Why should you have two copies then? I don't get it.

Comment: @MattDMo I believe Camera Uploads is a special folder in Dropbox (used by the e.g., Android app), I'm not sure you can move it...

Comment: @HaukeLaging Dropbox doesn't like symlinks. It immediately converts them to copies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have root on the system, you can use a bind mount. Note that this will leave you with an empty Camera Uploads directory in your ~/Dropbox/Pictures, but avoiding that adds much more complexity (unionfs of some sort).

```
# mount --bind ~user/Dropbox/Pictures ~user/Pictures
# mkdir -p ~user/Pictures/Camera\ Uploads
# mount --bind ~user/Dropbox/Camera\ Uploads ~user/Pictures/Camera\ Uploads
```

You can put these bind mounts in `/etc/fstab` or run them through `sudo`, of course.

Comment: This worked perfectly.